# Переменные в массиве PHP

Tags: массивы, php, mysql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как собрать переменные в один массив и отправить это все в БД?

```
$width=$_POST["width"];
$width2=$_POST["width2"]; //переменные input
$array = array(переменная,переменная);

INSERT INTO apps (width) VALUES ('$array') //Отправка в бд
```

Как правильно это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну у Вас в коде переменные и так собираются в один массив командой

```
$array = array(переменная,переменная);
```

Понятно что этот массив отправлять в бд нет никакого смысла. Скорее всего в бд запишется что-то вроде "Array" или вообще ошибка будет. Я честно говоря не очень понял, что у Вас не так. Ибо Вы привели код, который собирает переменные в массив.

Или вы хотите чтобы это всё в цикле собиралось? 
Вроде этого:

```
$array = array();
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
    array_push($array, $value);
}

INSERT INTO apps (width) VALUES ('$array') // хотя тут синтаксис не верный. Но вопрос не об этом...
```

**Дополнение:**

```
$params = '';
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
    $params .= $value.',';
}
substr($params,0,-1); //удаляем последний символ. Т.е запятую.

$query = "INSERT INTO apps (width) VALUES ($params)";
```

Я надеюсь вы знаете, что делать с переменной $query

Comment: Короче может я не правильно выразился но вопрос решился таким путем

    $arraywidth = $width .= $width2 .= $width3;
Теперь все переменные полей отправляются в БД. Теперь стоит вопрос как добавить в конец каждой переменной запятую.

Comment: Боже. Да что ж вы делаете? Для чего это всё? Что вы в итоге хотите получить?

Comment: $width=$_POST["width"];// значение поля инпут

    $array = array($width1, $width1, $width1);

Comment: ну так а не проще ли это всё в цикле сделать? 
Тогда можно будет добавлять новое поле input и не нужно будет исправлять php код

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста реализовать что то похожее на это чудо

    $array = array($width1, $width1, $width1);

Comment: Та я же Вам ответил как это сделать. В цикле foreach это всё и происходит

Comment: Пробовал через foreach, почему то у меня отправлялось только последнее значение (последней строки). Черканице пару строк как это реализовывается.

Comment: Дополнил ответ тем, что вам нужно

Answer (score 0):

А синтаксис БД выкинем нафиг?)

Делать обработчик, который будет массив в строку преобразовывать.

```
$array = array(10, 20, 30);
print("INSERT INTO apps VALUES ('".implode("','", $array)."')");
```

Comment: В базу добовляю так

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO apps (width) VALUES ('$info')");

Вопрос как собрать все переменные в один массив ?

Comment: Вопрос был в том как всунуть переменную в массив

    $array = array($width1, $width1, $width1);
    print("INSERT INTO apps VALUES ('".implode("','", $array)."')");

Но к сожалению такое не прокатит. Я просто в PHP слаб.